Why does using any in-built functions not rounding a 0.5 decimal to 1?
I need to round off each decimal values to its nearest whole number, anything less than 0.4 to be rounded off to 0, and 0.5 and above to be rounded off to 1.
But when i try that in C++ no matter which function i try to use it seems to round of 0.5 to 0 and not 1, it works fine for other decimal values but for 0.5, this happened to both positive and negative values as well.
Here is the code that i just made:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

int main(){
    using namespace std;
    int a, b, n;
    cin >> n;
    int arr[n];
    double prod;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cin >> a >> b;
        prod = a/b;
        if(prod < 0){
            arr[i] = (int)(prod-0.5);
        } else {
            arr[i] = (int)(prod+0.5);
        }
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
}

Here is the sample dataset that i have used for my testing (tried it with others as well but this was the one that was still there on my laptop so im putting it here):
`13 --> Size of the array.
571518625 -24104
-1893729058 -436796
2104753595 -158270
-822607240 72830
0 -79061
-627632490 -31441
369212137 18046
976324350 -57100
487246561 24578
-1317758661 119682
0 5341
1098940248 -68272
-923153725 61895`

The answer I got:
-23710 4335 -13298 -11294 0 19962 20459 -17098 19824 -11010 0 -16096 -14914
Against the answer I was suppose to get:
-23711 4336 -13299 -11295 0 19962 20460 -17099 19825 -11011 0 -16097 -14915

Looks like you want std::round() and friends. Just casting to int will truncate.

This "cin >> n;     int arr[n];" is not standard C++. It's a variable length array which is a language extension of some compilers, but it's not a standardized language feature. You should be using std::vector.

prod = a/b; integer division truncates and produces an int which the assignment then converts to a double. Fractional part is lost before the conversion. You want something like prod = static_cast<double>(a) / b; or directly use double type variables in the division so you don't get integer division.

"anything less than 0.4 to be rounded off to 0, and 0.5 and above to be rounded off to 1" -- That leaves 0.4 itself and the values between 0.4 and 0.5 unaccounted for. Is that intentional, or was that 0.4 supposed to be 0.5?

Did you look at the value of prod before trying to round it? Narrowing down an issue to a single line of code -- or even a single expression -- is a useful skill.

You can side-step commentary about your use of a variable-length array extension by keeping your [mre] focused on a single test case. Don't try to solve your puzzle/assignment in this question; just demonstrate the issue. For example, trimming down your code to a single, simple example gave me `#include 
int main() {
int a = 9, b = 5;
double prod = a/b;
int arr_i;
if (prod < 0) {
arr_i = (int)(prod-0.5);
} else {
arr_i = (int)(prod+0.5);
}
std::cout << arr_i << " ";
}(that's without checking the value ofprod`; that advice still stands, just as separate advice).

dont make two many steps at once when debugging. Here two steps were too many already. Your (int)(prod+0.5) would actually work, btu the issue is in the other step you make. You could have used directly double input and round that to see that (int)(0.6 + 0.5) results in the desired 1
